# Can I return True or False with filtering <class 'str'>?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset containing millions of rows. I am trying to do data validation to flag out strings/int/floats etc. After multiple tries with schema, pandera and other libraries that help with validation, I found that I have to convert the df column to it's true form.

So for example, I have a dataset that looks like this from read_csv. So all columns are read is string.

| Index | Item | Quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Apple | 20 | 30.5 |
| 1 | Banana | 5 | 3.4 |
| 2 | Coke | 3 | 1.2 |
| 3 | 123 | Dough | Ele |
| 4 | Ham | 85.6 | Pear |
| 5 | 56.1 | 9 | 20 |

I tried this function and was wondering if I can filter the column and return True.

```
def check_type(x):
    
     try: 
        return type(eval(x)) 
    
     except Exception as e:
        return type(x)

df.applymap(check_type)
```

Would something like   `not <class 'str'> in df['Item'] returns True` possible?

Comment: What is the actual rule that you want to implement? Exactly what should the result be for this input, and why? Please make sure you understand that *every value in a column has the same type, no matter what it looks like*. The `123` that you see for the `Item` of entry `3` is just as much a string as the `Ham` for the `Item` of entry `4`.

Comment: It seems like the real question is "how can I tell whether a string can be converted to a number with `int` and/or `float`?". Do I understand that properly? I.e., if you had an answer for that, would you be able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can map a function to the `item` column like this,

```
>>> df['Item'].map(lambda x: False if x.isalpha() else True)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
```

Comment: yes but I was advised it is quite unfeasible with 1 million rows due to the time complexity... if its possible I would not want to iterate through each row

Comment: with 1 million+ rows I would recommend using multiprocessing with this code, can you at least provide a sample output